# How to remove "Warning: Unresponsive Script"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery ajax code like this:

```
$.each(url_id, function(index, value) {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "webservices/insert-manual.php",
            data: { url_id: value},
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(response){
            if(response.code == "200"){
                $("#results").append('<div class="results-list"><strong>Well done!</strong></div>');
            }else{
                $("#results").append('<div class="results-list-error"><strong>Oh snap!</strong> There is no records to update in database.</div>');
            }
        }); 
    });
```

When i run this script I got this error message in mozilla alert.

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: http://localhost/jquery-project/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
```

and this ask me to `Stop Script` or `Continue`.

If I click on `Stop Script` then it stop the loop `$.each` or if I click on continue then it continue to run further code and after some time it again ask me.

My question is how can remove this alert.

Comment: This is a good signpost to the other low voted/not very clear duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
async: false,
```

This is causing the problem. It blocks your javascript until the page is loaded. Remove it.

It means that you're trying to run the code synchronously, e.g. in blocking mode.

Comment: if I will remove `async: false`, then it will work and complete the loop ?

Comment: which loop? I don't see any here?

Comment: `$.each(url_id, function(index, value) {` i used in my question

Comment: async:true means issuing ajax request with max speed of the PC against the server. Due to the browsers error message I assume the list is a bit longer and then its a bad idea.

Comment: I've never seen that async ajax reqs have ever blocked the browser...

Comment: But you should really consider to send all the requests in one big request => better performance

Comment: Thanks @bwoebi i removed `async: false` and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First: you can't. The purpose is exactly to prevent users from side effects of code like this.

Second: try to collect all urls in an array, pass this as one (1) ajax to the server, collect the replies per url in one (1) batch and append all those error messages. Leave out the "success", only report on errors ("no news is good news").

But even this may cause the error, if the list is long enough.

Setting the ajax to async:true may go faster but blcok the users PC (and probably your server...)

Comment: Exactly the opposite: `async` does **not** block.

Comment: @Axel Amthor I were using the same as you are saying to send big request to server but it returns the result after a long time. That is why I used this method to send one by one and display the result accordingly. can you please tell is there any other way to do it.

Comment: @deceze: yes, it doesn't block, I know. That means, its running through the list and issuing all that tons of calls against the server in milliseconds. And that may OVERLOAD the users PC or the server.

Comment: That's a suboptimal choice of words then. :) You *should* run the script asynchronously *non-blocking*, but code it in a way that not all requests are fired instantly (i.e. use a queue).